# Multi-tag url produces a long sequence of 'or's

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, tag-watching, new-nav

Apologies if this is a dupe, I couldn't fine one:

The new navigation seems to parse this url:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python%20or%20pandas%20or%20dataframes%20or%20windbg%20or%20networkx%20or%20scikit-learn%20or%20c%2b%2b?sort=newest&pageSize=50

into a large sequence of `or`'s:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&tags=c%2b%2b%20dataframes%20networkx%20or%20or%20or%20or%20or%20or%20pandas%20python%20scikit-learn%20windbg&mode=any

This produces an ugly favourites bar:

[image]

Could this be looked at as one of the fixes, thanks.

Comment: Similar question on [mso](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300282/url-with-several-tags-joined-by-or-is-broken)

Comment: @rene yes this is a dupe got my sites confused but this affects all sites I presume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have notice the same behaviour, but I think we just have to mark these tags as favorites then use the tagFilter parameter now :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&tagFilter=favorite

Comment: Cheers, that looks much better